# How to remove websocket connection onClose properly

Tags: javascript, websocket

Please take a look a this src-code:

```
var clients         = {}; // map<string, Connection> clients
var clientsReverse  = {}; // map<Connection, string> clientsReverse

webSocketServer.on('connection', function(newclient) { // newclient is connection Object

    newclient.on('message', function(message) {

        var data = JSON.parse(message);

        if (clients[data.name] === undefined) {
            clients[data.name]        = newclient;
            clientsReverse[newclient] = data.name;
        }

        // ...

    });

    newclient.on('close', function(){
        log(clientsReverse[newclient]); // prints always the same string

        // remove closed connection
        var key = clientsReverse[newclient];
        delete clientsReverse[newclient];
        delete clients[key];
    });
});
```

I have to remove a connection if the client gone away. As you can see I'm using two arrays for this, but unfortunately it does not work. If I try to disconnect 3 random clients, log print always the same name...

Any Idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's `object`, `array`'s syntax would be `[]`; And I believe the `newclient` is something like an `object`, not `string` or `number`, it probably just set a key like `[object object]` to `clientsReverse`, the `newclient` should contain some unique variable like `id`, `name`... etc. Log that `newclient`, see what it contain, then use something like `newclient.id` as key.

Comment: @fuyushimoya oh ok. I know it as associative array or map. newclient is an object.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `clients` nor `clientsReverse` is an array. Those are objects. Objects act kinda like hashmaps in JavaScript, so you can access their properties with strings. For example:

```
var a = { b: 5 };
console.log(a['b']); //5
```

If you try to make an index out of an object (`newclient` is an object), it will `toString` it first. The result of `newclient.toString()` is `[object Object]`, and it will be that for every object you use, doesn't matter that it's a different object. That's why even though you use different `newclient` objects, it always resolves to the same key.

I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve here. You can try using arrays (`[]`), but those can only have numerical indexes. You can also try using some kind of unique property of the client, their id or name perhaps?

Comment: ok I have to find the way, to remove newclient from the list. since it is closed connection and not valid any more.

Comment: You could use an array (a real array, `[]`), and iterate over it. Compare elements until you find the client you want to remove and remove it. You could compare the objects themselves, names or perhaps an id, if they have one.